# Codeigniter view executed twice when calling a function from constructor

Tags: php, constructor, codeigniter-3

I followed a tutorial on how to set up a login system for php apps in codeigniter. The logic when the user has session data is working great, but I have a problem when the user isn't logged in (f.ex. refreshes the page after a while). The view of "not_logged_in" gets executed twice when I were to call for the functin from constructor.
The following code works, but it means I gotta add the code for every function I add after.

```php
class App extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
      parent::__construct();



 }
 private function logged_in()
 {

      $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
      if (isset($is_logged_in) OR $is_logged_in)
      {
           return TRUE;
      }
      else
      {
           $data['title'] = 'Chyba přihlášení';
           $data['main_content'] = 'not_logged_in';
           $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
           return FALSE;
      }
 }

 function index()
 {
      if($this->logged_in())
      {
           $data['title'] = 'APLIKACE';
           $data['main_content'] = 'app_view';
           $data['userid'] = $this->session->userdata('userid'); //get userid from session
           $this->session->unset_userdata('userid'); //destroy the data
           $this->load->view('includes/template' , $data);
      }
 }


 function logout()
 {
     $this->session->sess_destroy();
     redirect('login');
 }


}
```

Now the real question, how would I go about putting the whole logic into a constructor without having to check for it in every function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `APPPATH.'core/MY_Controller.php'` file and put authentication logic in constructor there. Than extend that class from every controller (you need auth logic).

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct();
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->check_login();
    }

    protected function check_login()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        //here should be *AND* instead *OR* logic
        if (isset($is_logged_in) && !empty($is_logged_in))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login/index');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Login.php controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller//NOT extending MY_Controller to avoid infinite loop
{
    public function __construct();
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //here is login view
        //and logic of preserving session
        //with redirect to 'app/index' after successful login
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

App.php controller:

```
class App extends MY_Controller//extending MY_Controller to check login status
{
    public function __construct();
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //here is app dashboard view
    }

    public function statistics()
    {
        //here is some other method that requires logged in user
    }
}
```

I also would recommend you to check [Ion_auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) authentication system to see if suitable for you.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved the issue perfectly and my code looks neat with this solution. BTW is there something that could go wrong when using custom controller like this?
edit: I'll look into the auth system you linked to see if I could incorporate it into future projects

Comment: You are welcome. Just I don't know what did you mean with going wrong of custom controller. Using core classes is most usual thing if that was the question.